# Changing cleveref type for a single chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref

I have an appendix in my thesis that, due to `fancyheader` constraints, I define as `\chapter*` and not `\appendix`. However, now when I refer to it using `\cref` I get "chapter", I can change this manually, but I'm sure there is a way to define this using `cleverref`. Am I right? How to achieve this?

Edit: MWEs

The problem that sparked this. Using this code

```
\documentclass[final]{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \nouppercase{\leftmark}
    }

\fancyhead[R]{%
    \nouppercase{\rightmark}
    }
\clearpage
some text
\label{chapter}


\appendix
\chapter{A}

\fancyhead[L]{%
    \nouppercase{Appendix \leftmark}
    }
\clearpage
some text
\label{appendix}

\end{document}
```

I get this two headers
[image]

Which are what I want. However, the chapter intro page appears like that

[image]

Which I really don't like. Removing this is no problem, I replace the `\Chapter{A}` with `\Chapter{}` but then I the header losses the A. Alternatively, I can do the "ugly" solution and change the header definition in the appendix to

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \nouppercase{Appendix A}
    }
```

Which is what I did.

I thought about making the appendix simply a `chapter*` named `Appendix A`, but this broke cleverref, since it referred to the appendix as chapter. So is there a way to force cleverred to recognize a chapter as appendix?

Edit: The problem at hand.

In this setup, there are two problems. Placing `\cref{appendix}` someplace would result with "Chapter 1" and not with "Appendix A". Furthermore, the equation numbers are (1.n) instead of (A.n). I guess that my manual solution is the simplest. And that [Andrew's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261750/5366) answer has what I need.

Comment: Could provide a minimal compilable example?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't contain a `\cref` instruction, and hence doesn't generate the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: @Mico I know, what I wanted to know is how to fix that. I find the package documentation of cref (and latex in general) very confusing and I rellay mostly on my google-fu. I lack a lot of terms though and nine times out of ten, I search the wrong phrase.

Comment: @Yotam - The immediate issue is the following:  The code you've provided has no cross-referencing instructions. How do you expect readers of your posting to figure out what may be going wrong if there's nothing to go wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As there is no [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) this may not be exactly what is required *but* I gather that the problem is that [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) is printing "Chapter" for the appendix name when you would rather have "Appendix".

The [cleveref package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provides the `\crefformat` command for controlling how different labels are printed. One way around your problem is to make this command do different things for chapters and appendices. To do this `\crefformat` would need to know when the appendices start. So, I have made a counter `appendicesStart` that gives the "chapter number" of the first appendix after which I defined the cleveref chapter format using:

```
\crefformat{chapter}{% make cleveref's chapter format dynamic
  \ifnum#1<\arabic{appendicesStart}\relax Chapter~#1#2#3%
  \else Appendix%
  \fi%
}
```

Using this my mwe produces:

[image]

where "Chapter 1" and "Appendix" are labels produced by the `\cref{...}` command form `cleveref`. For this to work you need to set the value of the `appendicesStart` counter. This could be one by hand but instead I have defined a `\StartAppendices` command to keep track of this.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% OP said this was being used
\usepackage{cleveref}% OP said this was being used
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{appendicesStart}% counter to mark start of appendices
\setcounter{appendicesStart}{1000}% set to ridiculously high value by default
\AtBeginDocument{% set appendicesStart from aux file
  \setcounterref{appendicesStart}{AppendicesStart}%
}
\crefformat{chapter}{% make cleveref's chapter format dynamic
  \ifnum#1<\arabic{appendicesStart}\relax Chapter~#1#2#3%
  \else Appendix%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\StartAppendices{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \label{AppendicesStart}% save as reference to be read in AtBeginDocument
}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{First one}
  \label{C:first}

  \StartAppendices
  \chapter*{Second one}
  \label{C:second}

  \cref{C:first} and \cref{C:second}.

\end{document}
```

There are a few caveats:

- this will not work with numbered appendices
- this will not work if you have chapters after appendices
- this will *not* work with [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)

The first two problems are not that hard to deal with. (As the OP uses `\chapter*{...}` the first problem is probably not an iissue). Being able to use `hyperref` will require some thought.

Comment: Hey. I applied this, and it worked, however, it produced a new problem. My PDF readers (evince and okular) does not recognize a table of content. Did you experience the same thing?

Comment: @Yotam I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Given the edit that you made to your original question I don't think that I have answered your first question but I can't answer the question in your comment either unless you first clarify what it is you want. I suggest asking a new question and providing a *clear* [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I had two tabs open, one of your fix one for another problem I had with appendixes and my comment should have gone there. I'll update my question later today and let you know. Again, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be what you're after. After the `\appendix` directive, the code features the following instructions:

```
\chapter{}  \label{chap:app}
\renewcommand\leftmark{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\appendixname~\leftmark}}
```

Earlier in the document, the instruction `\cref{chap:app}` generates "appendix A" as the output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{title}  \label{chap:title}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\clearpage

some text

A cross-reference to \cref{chap:app}.

\appendix
\chapter{}  \label{chap:app}
\renewcommand\leftmark{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\appendixname~\leftmark}}
\clearpage

some text

A cross-reference to \cref{chap:title}.
\end{document}
```